# Atlassian Jira Helpdesk - Extract Helpdesk Ticket info from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

We're trying to build in a streamlined way of fast-tracking creating work items with a button which is injected by a Chrome Extension on our Jira Helpdesk Page. We currently have the button working and creating work items but now are looking to fill in the details of the work item from info that is present in the Jira helpdesk ticket. Which brings me to the real question:

Is there a Javascript object on Atlassian's Jira platform that contains this info? I've been exploring the different objects and found an object named JIRA that seems quite promising. Within this object, there are a few clues which makes me believe I'm on the right trail. For example, `JIRA.Users.LoggedInUser.userName()` returns the name of the person currently logged in (which could be used to record who is creating the Dev work item).

I've found another object within "JIRA" specifically called `JIRA.Issue` that has some functions such as `getIssueId()` but this returns null. We're mainly looking for info such as Ticket ID, Ticket Title, Description, Reporter, Link, etc.

Was just curious if anyone has had any experience on how to extract the helpdesk ticket info for a similar project. Searching documentation and google brings up little results so perhaps this isn't a viable option. Also open to other alternatives besides finding a javascript object on the page.

Thanks in advance.